# Creating a triangle with text on the sides

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am creating a puzzle with triangle pieces, like the picture below. The idea is to have a bunch of equilateral triangles, with different math questions/answers written on the sides of the triangle. I have no idea where to even start, so any information is helpful.

While this image shows it pieced together, it should be a document with a bunch of separate triangles that they will have to cut out and piece together in the correct positions.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 3):

This draws something of that sort. You probably need to change the formulae. If you want to rescale them to have all the same width, you can do that with `adjustbox`, but I personally do not like to use different font sizes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={pft(\x)=0-isodd(\x)*pow(-1,int((\x-1)/2))*120;}]
 \def\mylst{"y=x^2","y=2x+4","y=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}",%
    "y=x+2z","y=5x-19x^2","a^2+b^2=c^2","E=mc^2","E=a^2+b^2","h=x+y-z^2",%
    "s=t+u","r=u\cdot v"}
 \draw[very thick] (0,0) foreach \X in {1,...,11} 
 {\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mylab}{{\mylst}[\X-1]}} 
 -- node[auto,sloped]{$\mylab$} ++ ({pft(\X)}:5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Here is what I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=7.103727042249676cm,y=7.103727042249676cm]
\clip(-0.06759227604311863,-0.056850010368415166) rectangle (1.0585771210099646,0.9172736328491257);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (0.,0.)-- (1.,0.);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (1.,0.)-- (0.5,0.8660254037844388);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (0.5,0.8660254037844388)-- (0.,0.);
\draw (0.55,0.5) node[anchor=north west] {\rotatebox{120}{$y' = \dfrac{x^2-4x}{(x-2)^2}$}};
\draw (0.35,0.1) node[anchor=north west] {$e^{4x + 5} = y$};
\draw (0.17,0.5) node[anchor=north west] {\rotatebox{240}{$y' = \dfrac{19}{2\sqrt{19x}}$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Gives me exactly what I need. Now I just need to create a bunch more to finish it out!